# Remove page number, if there is only one page in a section

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, conditionals, fancyhdr

In my current project, I want to create worksheets that I can print out and distribute. To do this, I want to reset the page number for each worksheet, but only display the page number if the worksheet has more than one page (for example, if it has a back page). If the worksheet has only one page, the page number should be hidden so that there is no unnecessary confusion about where page 2 etc. is. Can I do this with `fancyhdr`?

Here is MWE. Each worksheet starts with its own section. Note that I use LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=4cm,headheight=0mm, footskip=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyhead[RO,RE]{Bla}
\fancyhead[LO,LE]{Bla}
\fancyfoot{} 
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{}
\fancyfoot[LO,CE]{}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace{0.25cm}}
\makeatother

\definecolor{mainblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}[StylisticSet={7,9}]

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.25\baselineskip}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily\color{mainblue}\centering}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
\setsansfont{Quattrocento Sans}

\newcommand{\head}[1]{%
\clearpage
\noindent
\vspace*{0.3cm}
\section{#1}
\vspace*{0.3cm}
\setcounter{page}{1}
}

\begin{document}

\head{Only one page}
Please hide page number below.

\head{Two pages}
First page. Please don't hide page number below.

\clearpage

Second page

\end{document}
```

I know I can do this manually by defining a new pagestyle, but that would be too tedious for me. I have already created a lot of worksheets that I would like to merge into one project and it would take a lot of time to see, if they all fit on one page. Does anyone have ideas what I could do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\label` to store the page number just after issuing `\clearpage` and at the next run the test whether the number of pages is 1 will be successful and `\thepage` will be skipped.

I fixed `headheight` that *cannot* be set to zero if you want headers. Also `fontenc` should not be loaded along with `fontspec`. I reorganized the preamble to first load packages and then do setting.

Use `\titlespacing` rather than `\vspace` around `\section`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[
  left=2.5cm,
  right=2.5cm,
  top=3cm,
  bottom=4cm,
  headheight=14.5pt,% <-- as recommended by fancyhdr
  footskip=10mm
]{geometry}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% NOT with fontspec
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{refcount}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

%%% fancyhdr

\fancyhead{} 
\fancyhead[RO,RE]{Bla}
\fancyhead[LO,LE]{Bla}
\fancyfoot{} 
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{}
\fancyfoot[LO,CE]{}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{\maybethepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}


%%% colors
\definecolor{mainblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67}

%%% fontspec and unicode-math
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}[StylisticSet={7,9}]
\setmainfont{EB Garamond} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
\setsansfont{Quattrocento Sans}


%%% generic
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace{0.25cm}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.25\baselineskip}

%%% titlesec
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily\color{mainblue}\centering}

%%% personal commands
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\head}[1]{%
  \label{NPAGES\arabic{section}}%
  \clearpage
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
  \section{#1}
}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \label{NPAGES\arabic{section}}%
}
\newcommand{\maybethepage}{%
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{NPAGES\arabic{section}}=1
  \else
    \thepage
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\head{Only one page}
Please hide page number below.

\head{Two pages}
First page. Please don't hide page number below.

\clearpage

Second page

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, and also thank you for reorganizing my preamble! Personally, I am very messy type of person, so my preambles are always very chaotic (good thing is that my students will never see them).

Answer (score 4):

Since your `\section`s are set/started on a new page, you can condition on the page number within the footer, as these are set as the pages are shipped out. So, I would update `\head` to capture the current section's (last) page number:

```
\newcommand{\head}[1]{%
  \label{last-page-for-\thesection}% Store last page of current section
  \clearpage
  \vspace*{0.3cm}
  \section{#1}
  \vspace*{0.3cm}
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
}
```

Also capture the final `\section`'s last page number:

```
\AtEndDocument{\label{last-page-for-\thesection}}% Capture last page of final section
```

And then condition on the page number setting using [`refcount`](//ctan.org/pkg/refcount):

```
\usepackage{refcount}
% Condition on placing footer page number; if \section has more than 1 page
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{\ifnum\getpagerefnumber{last-page-for-\thesection}>1 \thepage\fi}
```

Here is a complete, minimal example:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{extarticle}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[RO,RE]{Right header}
\fancyhead[LO,LE]{Left header}
% Condition on placing footer page number; if \section has more than 1 page
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{\ifnum\getpagerefnumber{last-page-for-\thesection}>1 \thepage\fi}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove page header rule
\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\hspace{0.25cm}}
\makeatother

\definecolor{mainblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily\color{mainblue}\centering}

\usepackage{refcount}
\AtEndDocument{\label{last-page-for-\thesection}}% Capture last page of final section
\newcommand{\head}[1]{%
  \label{last-page-for-\thesection}% Store last page of current section
  \clearpage
  \vspace*{0.3cm}
  \section{#1}
  \vspace*{0.3cm}
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
}

\begin{document}

\head{Only one page}
Please hide page number below.

\head{Two pages}
First page. Please don't hide page number below.

\clearpage

Second page

\end{document}
```